# Product of well supported objects is well supported

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a regular category, $A\in\mathcal{C}$ and suppose the two canonical projections $A\times A \rightrightarrows A$ are equal. I'd like to show that then $A\cong 1$, where $1$ is the terminal object of $\mathcal{C}$. This is a step in the proof of Lemma 1.3.8 in The Elephant, and I can't see why its true. Showing that $A$ must be terminal seems difficult, since there's no obvious way of getting an arrow $X\to A$ for every $X\in\mathcal{C}$.

For reference, here's the actual result:

[image]

Comment: If the two projection $A\times A\rightrightarrows A$ are equal, then $A\to 1$ is monic. Since $A\to 1$ is, by assumption, a cover, it's an isomorphism, hence $A$ is terminal.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Got it, thanks! I was thinking this was supposed to hold in general and was forgetting that $A\to 1$ is a cover.